# Whitespace issue in text to image conversion

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have a C# WinForms application that parses a text file and converts it into an image. The application works fine for normal text files. The problem I am facing is with the whitespaces in the text.

The code is:-

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(file);

Image img = DrawText(text);
img.Save("c:\\LoRa Demo\\pic.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I am using the `Graphics.DrawString()` in the `DrawText()` to convert the text into image.

When parsing the following text, the white spaces don't occupy the same width in the string buffer as in the text file.

Text File content:-

```
***************************
******           **********
******           **********
***************************
***************************
```

Debugging shows the following image in the string buffer:-

[image: Debug Image]

The output image is same as the one in the buffer:-

[image: Final output]

How to parse the text file properly and convert it to image as in the text file ?

Comment: This is probably because of the different fonts used in your text editor and by the  `DrawText` method

Comment: @Alex I am using the DefaultFont in the DrawText method

Comment: What font is that exactly. and what font does your text editor displays text in?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h60yx8s5(v=vs.110).aspx 
as you can see the DrawText has an overload that takes a font as a parameter. Try to match this parameter with the font used in your text editor

Comment: @Alex seems like it was the font issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

See: [A list of monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces)